# Find Facebook UID of Social Graph Search Results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the Facebook UID's of results returned from a Social Graph search. For example, lets say I were to search "People who like surfing and live in Florida" I would then want to grab the Facebook UIDs of all of these search results.

I can do this one at a time by opening each person's profile and entering their profiles URL into a site like findmyfacebookid.com.

I am just hoping there is a quicker way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas on where I might start? Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting userid's you may use graph API calls.There isnt any need for an external website.

Use this API request,

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{USERNAME} OR {USERID}

Eg: http://graph.facebook.com/mark
```

And you will get a result set of basic profile parameters in a JSON format.

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```